# Can we exchange logical disjunction for UNION ALL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I saw in that somebody exchange below code:

```
SELECT
    PK1
    , PK2
    , PK3
    , PK4
    , C
    , B
    , SUM(NUMERIC_1)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_2)
    , MAX(NUMERIC_3)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_4)
FROM MATDOC_EXTRACT
WHERE A = ''
      AND (
          (
              (
              B = ''
              OR B = 'K'
          )
              AND (
                  C = '01'
                  OR C = '02'
                  OR C = '07'
                  OR C = '08'
              )
          )
          OR (
              B = ''
              AND (
                  C = '03'
                  OR C = '04'
              )
          )
      )
GROUP BY PK1
         , PK2
         , PK3
         , PK4
         , C
         , B;
```

for this one

```
SELECT
    PK1
    , PK2
    , PK3
    , PK4
    , C
    , B
    , SUM(NUMERIC_1)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_2)
    , MAX(NUMERIC_3)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_4)
FROM sap.MATDOC_EXTRACT
WHERE A = N''
      AND B = N''
      AND C IN (N'01', N'02', N'07', N'08', N'03', N'04')
GROUP BY PK1
         , PK2
         , PK3
         , PK4
         , C
         , B
UNION ALL
SELECT
    PK1
    , PK2
    , PK3
    , PK4
    , C
    , B
    , SUM(NUMERIC_1)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_2)
    , MAX(NUMERIC_3)
    , SUM(NUMERIC_4)
FROM sap.MATDOC_EXTRACT
WHERE A = N''
      AND B = N'K'
      AND C IN (N'01', N'02', N'07', N'08')
GROUP BY PK1
         , PK2
         , PK3
         , PK4
         , C
         , B;
```

are they equal ?

Comment: Yes, they are, but *only* because the conditions are non-overlapping and because they are included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One potentially important difference is that in the second case the literals are `nvarchar` and in the first case they are `varchar`.

Ignoring that aspect however...

Yes

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  predicate_a
        OR predicate_b
```

Can be re-written as

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  predicate_a
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  predicate_b
```

As long as `predicate_a` and `predicate_b` are mutually exclusive.

Otherwise rows that match both `predicate_a` and `predicate_b` will incorrectly be returned twice.

In this case as the two branches of the `UNION ALL` have `predicate_a` includes `B = N''` and `predicate_b` includes `B = N'K'` then this condition is met.

In your case you have 10 different equality predicates on `A, B, C` - so if you have an index with those columns in some order then potentially it could be resolved by ten seek predicates.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '' | '' | 01 |
| '' | '' | 02 |
| '' | '' | 07 |
| '' | '' | 08 |
| '' | K | 01 |
| '' | K | 02 |
| '' | K | 07 |
| '' | K | 08 |
| '' | '' | 03 |
| '' | '' | 04 |

Rewriting `OR` as `UNION ALL` can sometimes be a useful technique when the query written with `OR` doesn't give the desired index seeks or has other undesirable aspects.

If I try

```
CREATE TABLE T1(A VARCHAR(1), B VARCHAR(1), C VARCHAR(2), INDEX IX (A, B, C))

UPDATE STATISTICS T1 WITH ROWCOUNT = 50000000, PAGECOUNT = 500000
UPDATE STATISTICS T1 IX WITH ROWCOUNT = 50000000, PAGECOUNT = 500000
            
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE A = ''
      AND (
          (
              (
              B = ''
              OR B = 'K'
          )
              AND (
                  C = '01'
                  OR C = '02'
                  OR C = '07'
                  OR C = '08'
              )
          )
          OR (
              B = ''
              AND (
                  C = '03'
                  OR C = '04'
              )
          )
      )
```

Then the execution plan looks like

[image]

The execution plan does essentially break it into two separate index seek operators and `UNION ALL` them both together

```
  |--Sort(DISTINCT ORDER BY:([Bmk1000] ASC))
       |--Concatenation
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[IX]), SEEK:(
                [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='01' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='02' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='07' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='08' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='K' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='01' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='K' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='02' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='K' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='07' 
                OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='K' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='08') ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[IX]), SEEK:(
               [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='03' 
            OR [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[A]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[B]='' AND [tempdb].[dbo].[T1].[C]='04') ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Between the two seek operators the full 10 index seek ranges are expanded out.

For some reason it doesn't seem to see that they are non overlapping however and has a step to remove duplicates.

The `UNION ALL` rewrite does avoid this in this case

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE A = ''
      AND B = ''
      AND C IN ('01', '02', '07', '08', '03', '04')
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE A = ''
      AND B = 'K'
      AND C IN ('01', '02', '07', '08')
```

[image]